# Obtaining start and end Date Objects using the component methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

(eternicode) I'm using a range datepicker for my form.

```
<div class="input-daterange col-md-9 input-group" id="act">
    <input class="form-control" name="act_1" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input class="form-control" name="act_2" type="text">
</div>
```

i want to get both values in Date Object to later replace the data sent on the form with the ISO8601 format to preserve timezones.

i have used

```
$(element).datepicker("getDate");

$(element).datepicker("getDates");
```

but i haven't obtained any success. Anyone has an idea of what it is the rigth way to obtain this information ?

Comment: Which library are you using for date time?

Comment: None, I'm using EcmaScript 5.1 and their native Date Object

Comment: For this $(element).datepicker("getDates"); ?

Comment: Es/its bootstrap-datepicker by eternicode v1.6.0, saludos.

Comment: You want both values in one Date object, or you are having problem with .datepicker("getDate"); method ?

Comment: I want to acces to both date values as es5.1 date objects. I can use getDate but only seems to work when is not a range datepicker